# Overload compound operators like +=

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, compound-assignment

Is it possible to overload operator += directly in Scala? It might be useful for some complex types, where a += b may have more efficient and simpler implementation that a = a + b.

The case I encountered recently is I am providing operators for `Vector3f` from jMonkeyEngine (com.jme.math). A natural implementation could look like:

```
  import com.jme3.math.{Matrix3f, Vector3f}

  object JMEMathOperators {
    implicit class Vector3fMath(val a: Vector3f) extends AnyVal {
      def - (b: Vector3f) = a subtract b
      def + (b: Vector3f) = a add b
      def * (b: Vector3f) = a mult b
      def * (b: Float) = a mult b

      def += (b: Vector3f) = a addLocal b
    }
  }
```

In spite of no compile errors, my `+=` implementation is never called. The difference is not that important in this case, `addLocal` efficiency is only marginally better than `add`, but one can image there are some complex classes where the difference could be important.

Comment: I was wrong, the += is called. I though it is not because a breakpoint placed on the corresponding line did not trigger, but by placing a println calls into both + and += I can see it is called.

Comment: Which IDE? Does removing `extends AnyVal` let you set a breakpoint?

Comment: @som-snytt I am using InteliJ IDEA 13.1 Ultimate with Scala plugin. Yes, after removing "extends AnyVal" the breakpoint hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible to provide your own implementation for `+=`, but I suspect your issue comes from the implicit conversion.

If `Vector3f` already provides a `+=` method, calling it won't trigger the implicit conversion from `Vector3f` to `Vector3fMath`.

For example, if `a` and `b` are both `Vector3f`, doing

```
a += b
```

will call the `+=` method on `Vector3f`, which is completely expected.

In order to trigger the implicit conversion you need to use a method which is not already defined `Vector3f`. You have to choose another name, perhaps another symbol.

---

### Update

Ok, so `Vector3f` doesn't define a `+=` (since it's a Java class). Then your code should work fine, the error is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Vector3f is Java object, therefore it certainly does not provide any operators like +=. However you are right the implicit conversion may make the things different here.